# Looking for Harel state diagraming tool

Tags: uml, diagram

I am looking for a modeling system that can do [Harel state transition diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram#Harel_statechart). The paper on this system is provided [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dharel/SCANNED.PAPERS/Statecharts.pdf). Specifially I would like a system that would allow:

1. Modeling of statecharts
2. Zooming in and out of states, and auto hiding of states at some zoom level
3. Concurrent states, as described in the paper
4. Ability to collaboratively edit (not required, but would be really nice)

Any information on what you use and why would be invaluable. Thank you.

Comment: UML's statemodels were based on Harel.  Most any UML tool will let you build hierarchical state models with concurrent states, though don't know of any offhand that do zooming in/out.  As for collaboration: don't know any that support interactive (concurrent) buildind the same diagram though many support a multi-user, version controlled repository (e.g. Enterprise Architect).  hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Harel statecharts[5] are gaining widespread usage since a variant has become part of the Unified Modeling Language (UML).  (wiki)

So any UML diagraming tools may satisfy your needs.  I may advice SPARX EA UML tool. You can download a free trial from their web pages. http://www.sparxsystems.com/

- Tools allow you to model collaboratively(!) ( place the project file on a shared network drive,Replication,XMI Import/Export)
- It supports UML 2 ( you can show concurrent states / substates)
- **Zooming in and out of states ??** You may achive this by making a state Composite State( so details of a State will be hiden in the first diagram  and when you click on that state you can able to reach its internal details)

PS:

In reality No UML tool  can give you ability to model collaboratively. You can model collaboratively by using just simple tools. Then use a tool for doc if needed.

> Room, Walls, and Supplies for
>   Whiteboards or "Whiteboard sheets"  http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/index.php?title=Course_Environment_-_Workshop_Style7

Answer (score 4):

Yakindu looks good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10081752/506073

Direct link: http://www.statecharts.org